# deviance() function returns odd value

Tags: r, lme4

See the following example code:

```
library(lme4)
M100 <- glmer(vs ~ wt + (1|cyl), data=mtcars, family=binomial("logit"))
deviance(M100)
summary(M100)$AICtab["deviance"]
```

the deviance function returns 13.95 but reading the deviance from the model summary object returns 24.76. What's going on here?

Comment: Both return 24.76 for me

Comment: Are you sure? I just started a fresh R session and still get the same result. Maybe a version issue? R-3.2.2 32-bit on my side.

Comment: not sure why this is. Maybe a `lme4` issue?

Comment: @LyzandeR What are your R and `lme4` versions? With R `3.2.2` and `lme4` version `1.1-10`, I cannot get similar results.

Comment: @Pascal `lme4_1.1-7 ` and `R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)` on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: @LyzandeR  Tried on: a) `R version 3.1.3` (with `lme4 1.1-7`), b) `R version 3.2.2` (with `lme4 1.1-10`). Similar values with a), different values with b). There is definitively a problem in the new version.

Comment: Let's see if Ben Bolker comes around here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug; you're seeing the difference between different definitions of the deviance. `deviance(M100)` gives the relative, conditional deviance, while `summary(M100)$AICtab["deviance"]` (also equal to `-2*logLik(M100)`) gives the absolute, unconditional deviance [see below for definitions].

The change is cited in the [`NEWS` for 1.1-8](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/news.html), as

> deviance() now returns the deviance, rather than half the negative log-likelihood, for GLMMs fitted with Laplace (the behaviour for LMMs and GLMMs fitted with nAGQ>1 has not changed)

There is quite a bit of information in the Details section of `?deviance.merMod`:

> Deviance and log-likelihood of GLMMs:
>
> One must be careful when defining the deviance of a GLM.  For
>        example, should the deviance be defined as minus twice the
>        log-likelihood or does it involve subtracting the deviance for a
>        saturated model?  To distinguish these two possibilities we refer
>        to absolute deviance (minus twice the log-likelihood) and relative
>        deviance (relative to a saturated model, e.g. Section 2.3.1 in
>        McCullagh and Nelder 1989).  With GLMMs however, there is an
>        additional complication involving the distinction between the
>        likelihood and the conditional likelihood.  The latter is the
>        likelihood obtained by conditioning on the estimates of the
>        conditional modes of the spherical random effects coefficients,
>        whereas the likelihood itself (i.e. the unconditional likelihood)
>        involves integrating out these coefficients. The following table
>        summarizes how to extract the various types of deviance for a
>        ‘glmerMod’ object.

```
                     conditional        unconditional 
   relative   ‘deviance(object)’         NA in ‘lme4’ 
   absolute  ‘object@resp$aic()’  ‘-2*logLik(object)’
```

> [caveats abridged]
>
> For more information about this topic see the ‘misc/logLikGLMM’
>        directory in the package source.

Comment: Forgot to check the NEWS file. My bad.